# Can I link maxOccurs in my schema to a value of another attribute in the target xml file?

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd

I'm defining an xml schema for a file that looks something like this:

```
<data>
    <config><segmentcount value="10"/></config>
    <foos>
        <foo>
            <segments>
                <segment data="X"/>
                <segment data="X"/>
                <segment data="X"/>
                <segment data="X"/>
                <segment data="X"/>
            </segments>
        </foo>
        <foo>
            <segments>
                ...
```

I've already made a schema for the general structure.  However I want to enforce that the number of segment elements in segments is always the same as the value attribute of segmentcount.  In the maxOccurs attribute of segments, I tried the xpath `/aitt:data/aitt:config/aitt:segmentcount[1]@value`, but the parser told me than maxOccurs has to be a non-negative int or `unbounded`.

Is there a trick to do this?

Cheers in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't (as far as I know) a way to do this with XSD. You probably need to consider using [Schematron](http://www.schematron.com/) rules to achieve this sort of validation. I've had success with storing Schematron rules in annotation elements of my schemas.

Comment: Both the two answers so far are correct, but I'm going to tick this one for the schematron link.  Thanks for the info, guys.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's a way to link the schema and the data in the fashion you're desiring.